# How to avoid overlapping of Rapahel js path

Tags: jquery, svg, raphael, graphael

I have a flow chart which is based on Raphael js. it is same as that of http://raphaeljs.com/graffle.html. however since i have many rectangular Raphael boxes and my line path is of straight line and NOT curvy as shown in the above example. In this straight line type, these lines overlap sometime and so it is hard to tell which one is connecting which boxes.

Please let me know if i can achieve this and how.

Update :Attaching my current flow diagram jpeg. as you can see that connector lines are crossing over the Raphael shapes and also it is very hard to tell from where lines are starting.
[image]

Comment: Can you share some code, its difficult to know how to offer advice without it.

Comment: JDev -- in your implementation, do you want to support multi-segment linear connectors (i.e., L-shaped) or simple linear fragments?  An example of what you have so far would be very helpful.

Comment: thanks for the responses. Since i don't know much how to work on JS Fiddle, i prepared one Fiddle, which is not 100% working(i.e line connector are not working in this, so commented it at the end). I want L-shaped connector and not the curvy(C type path). i don't want that connector ran over the shapes and user should know the flow clearly. In my Fiddle example, i want to connect first shape to connect to other shapes. Fiddle is here. http://jsfiddle.net/E7nm4/16/. i would really appreciate your help.

Comment: Could someone please give direction how to achieve this?

Comment: How about looping through all your boxes and calling .toFront() to move them in front of the paths.

Comment: Neil: still in that case also, it would be hard to tell which line is originating from which boxes.

Comment: is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Have you solved the issue?