# How to update raphael Text dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael, graphael

I am drawing a flow chart based on Raphael shapes & Text. On page load, i drew the rapahel shapes with text inside. this text is some status. there is some background processing happening which is changing the status. Now i want to update this status(which is a rapahel text inside raphael shape)on a button click without redrawing the over flow chart shapes again. i.e i wants to update just the text inside the shape. Here both shapes and texts are in array. I am using json to get the status.

Please refer following stackoverflow question for the code and flow chart. I am looking for a pointer to achieve this. i cannot get the whole code because of the server side scripting dependency

[How to avoid overlapping of Rapahel js path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718943/how-to-avoid-overlapping-of-rapahel-js-path)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `raphText` is your RaphaelJS text element reference then `raphText.attr("text", "new status");` will change the text content.

For further information: have a look at http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Element.attr .