# Is it possible to group all the related elements using a SQL statement

Tags: sql, database

I want a SQL statement which can run on all the platforms and give the result in tree structure (not a real tree structure though)format.i.e all the related columns appears together. is it possible to achieve the following format using a sql. I have a simple table with three columns(GROUP_STEP,PREDECESSOR,COLUMNNUM). expected output
[image]

Platform supported : Oracle, SQL Server, DB2 and Sybase. I am looking for a SELECT statement from the table having following data in different format.

After @diaho suggestion , following is the output
[image]

Comment: You missed adding something to "output" section probably?

Comment: You may want to clarify that. Also, what are *all the platforms*?

Answer (score 0):

```
select groupnum,predecessor ,count(groupnum) as columnum group by groupnum,predecessor
```

if you give more details on table schema answer may change !!!

Comment: pls let me know what details you want. btw it is the same structure which diaho has mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your table, I'm assuming that you only have the `Group_Step` and `Predecessor` columns in your raw table and that the `ColumnNum` column represents the total number of levels for a leaf in your tree. For example, since `PC_Wrap1` has the `Predecessor` `BENEFITS` which has the `Predecessor` `COPY_BUDG` it has a total of 3 'levels'. If that is the case, you need a recursive query to calculate the `ColumnNum` value. I can't speak to *all platforms*, but for SQL Server, you can use a CTE:

**EDIT**: Removed 'dreaded non-standard square brackets' per a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion :)

```
-- Setup table
CREATE TABLE #Temp
(
    Group_Step VARCHAR(100),
    Predecessor VARCHAR(100)
)

-- Setup dummy data
INSERT INTO #Temp
(
    Group_Step,
    Predecessor
)
SELECT 'ACT_BD_ACT', '' UNION
SELECT 'COPY_BUDG', '' UNION
SELECT 'COPY_BUDG2', '' UNION
SELECT 'BENEFITS', 'COPY_BUDG' UNION
SELECT 'BENEFITS', 'COPY_BUDG2' UNION
SELECT 'PC_WRAP1', 'BENEFITS' UNION
SELECT 'PC_WRAP2', 'BENEFITS' UNION
SELECT 'ALLC1', '' UNION
SELECT 'ALLC2', '' UNION
SELECT 'ALLC3', 'ALLC2' UNION
SELECT 'TCP1', 'ALLC3' UNION
SELECT 'TCP1', 'ALLC4' UNION
SELECT 'COPY_BUDG3', '' UNION
SELECT 'COPY_BUDG4', '';

-- Actual solution starts here:
WITH Result
(
    Group_Step,
    Predecessor,
    ColumnNum
)
AS
(
-- Anchor member definition
SELECT
    Group_Step,
    Predecessor AS Predecessor,
    1 AS ColumnNum
FROM
    #Temp
WHERE
    Predecessor = ''
UNION ALL
-- Recursive member definition
SELECT
    t.Group_Step,
    t.Predecessor,
    ColumnNum + 1 AS ColumnNum
FROM
    #Temp AS t
JOIN
    Result AS r
ON
    t.Predecessor = r.Group_Step    
)
-- Statement that executes the CTE
SELECT DISTINCT
    Group_Step,
    Predecessor,
    ColumnNum
FROM
    Result
-- EDIT #2: Adding ORDER BY per Op's comment
ORDER BY
    ColumnNum

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

Comment: If you remove those dreaded non-standard square brackets this will actually work on all DBMS (apart from setting up the test data)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: This will probably not work in Sybase, as [Sybase appears to require the `RECURSIVE` keyword](http://dcx.sybase.com/1200/en/dbusage/recursive-table-expr-sqlug.html "Recursive common table expressions") to be specified after `WITH` when the clause contains a recursive CTE definition. (And this answer does use a recursive CTE.) The other three of the four products mentioned by the OP, however, do not support the RECURSIVE keyword.

Comment: @diaho:you got my requirement.i am trying to draw flow chart like in my below question(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14718943/how-to-avoid-overlapping-of-rapahel-js-path), but since connector lines overlap, i planning to use the tree type of data structure. when i try your above code in Oracle, it is correctly generating the column num(or leaf level), however i found that some Group_Step appears first in the predecessor column and then in the Group_Step level. Basically, in my loop i am reading Group_Step and creating one shape for each group_step as per their colnum position.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you should just need an `ORDER BY ColumnNum` added to the query. I've updated my answer